# Images not showing up on JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, jframe

I am having some trouble getting both the squares I created in the program, and the ImageIcon imported to show up on my JPanel. I have been at this for a while now, and still am unable to figure out what I can do to make them show up, and allows the player image to move. Here is the first piece of my code which is the Maze class:

```
public class Maze extends JPanel{
int[][][] mazeArray; //will be defined in the loop depending on how many rectangles are spawned, also for making sure the player can't walk over the walls (first is what number wall it is, second is the x coordiante of the wall, and third is the y coordinate of the wall)
//depending on whether or not the rctangle is vertical or horizontal it will use both values for its height and width (vertical would have sideX for the height, and sideY for the width; this would be the opposite for the horizontal rectangle)
int sideX = 50; //x side length
int sideY = 50; //y side length
int x;
int y;
//setters and getters for use later (for changing the rctangles location and size)
public void setSideX(int sideX){
    this.sideX = sideX;
}
public int getSideX(){
    return sideX;
}

public void setSideY(int sideY){
    this.sideY = sideY;
}
public int getSideY(){
    return sideY;
}

public void setCoordinates(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}
//end setters and getters   
public void generateMaze(){
    //the left side of the maze
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //ten blocks on the left side
        setX(0); //x is always 0 for the left side
        setY(getY() + 50); //adds 50 to the previous Y coordinate amount, m   making it go down the whole left side
    }
    setY(0); //set y back to zero to be able to start the right column of blocks
    //the right side of the maze
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        setX(500); //x is always 500 for the right side
        setY(getY() + 50); //does the same as it did on the left side,   except on the right
    }
    setY(0); //set y to zero again
    setX(50); //start x at 50 since there is no need to remake the corners
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //only goes up to 8 this this time because   the corners of the maze can be ignored
        setY(0); //just in case y changes back
        setX(getX() + 50); //x increases by 50 each time
    }
    setY(500);
    setX(50);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //same as above except for the bottom
        setY(500);
        setX(getX() + 50);
    }
    //the maze walls are now generated
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ //for painting the rectangles
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), sideX, sideY); //uses x and y coordinates defined in the generateMaze loop, and the uses whatever current value for the two side, depending on what type of rectangle it is
}
}
```

This is what I am using to create the mazes walls. Now comes the Player class which deals with the player image, player coordinates, and the player's movement speed:

```
public class Player {
//Player starts in the top left corner
int playerX = 50;
int playerY = 50;
int moveSpeed = 5; //I can edit move speed here
Image character;

//getters and setters to utilize the player's location and image
public Player(){ //constructor for initial starting points
    playerX = 50;
    playerY = 50;
    ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon("E://Workspace//Maze//images//Player.jpg");
    character = player.getImage();
}

public void setPlayerX(int playerX){
    this.playerX = playerX;
}
public int getPlayerX(){
    return playerX;
}

public void setPlayerY(int playerY){
    this.playerY = playerY;
}
public int getPlayerY(){
    return playerY;
}

public void setMoveSpeed(int moveSpeed){
    this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
}
public int getMoveSpeed(){
    return moveSpeed;
}

public Image getPlayerImage(){
    return character;
}
}
```

Next is where I think the problem is occurring for the player's image (for the maze I think it is something in the Maze class itself, although it could be a problem in the Layout class as well):

```
public class Layout extends JPanel implements ActionListener { //GUI with a non null FlowLayout
Maze m = new Maze();
Player p = new Player();

//500 x 500 seemed like a good size for the maze game
int x = 500;
int y = 500;
Image player;
JPanel panel;

public Layout() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //same as the JFrame
    panel.addKeyListener(new Move(p));
    panel.setFocusable(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); //background of the maze
    m.generateMaze(); //create the maze
}

//for use in setting and getting the borders of the game
public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public JPanel getPanel(){
    return panel;
}
@Override //so it can repaint as needed
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(p.getPlayerImage(), p.getPlayerX(), p.getPlayerY(), this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    repaint();
}
}

class Move implements KeyListener { //for player movement
final Player p;
Move(Player p){
    this.p = p;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent press) { //for the movement in the game
    //I used both keys so that if the player woukld like to use WASD or the arrow keys either will work
    if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        //move up
        p.setPlayerY(p.getPlayerY() - p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
    else if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        //move down
        p.setPlayerY(p.getPlayerY() + p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
    else if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        //move left
        p.setPlayerX(p.getPlayerX() - p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
    else if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        //move right
        p.setPlayerX(p.getPlayerX() + p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent release) {
    //nothing is needed here
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    //does nothing if a key is type (no need for it)
}
}
```

Lastly is the class that runs it, although I don't think there is any issue here, but just in case I will throw it in here anyway:

```
public class Play extends JPanel {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    play();
}

public static void play() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    Layout l = new Layout();
    JPanel j = l.getPanel();

    f.setTitle("Maze Game for final project");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(l.getX(), l.getY()); //size can be changed in layout
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.add(j); //adds the panel
}
}
```

I am trying to be able to have the player's image spawn at 50, 50 on start up, and then also have the walls spawn at start up as well. However currently the only thing that is showing up for the JPanel is the yellow background. Help would be greatly appreciated!

New updated code here:

```
    public static void play() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    Layout l = new Layout();

    f.setTitle("Maze Game for final project");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(l.getX(), l.getY()); //size can be changed in layout
    f.add(new Layout()); //adds the panel
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

and also for the Layout constructor

```
    public Layout() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    addKeyListener(new Move(p));
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    m.generateMaze();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I've gone through all of your code, but one thing did strike me:

Your Layout class extends JPanel and overrides paintComponet, but you never use this class as a JPanel. Instead you use some other JPanel variable within it called `panel`. Get rid of that variable and instead use the JPanel that is the Layout class itself, and at least *some* of your problems may be fixed.

e.g.,

```
public class Layout extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   Maze m = new Maze();
   Player p = new Player();
   int x = 500;
   int y = 500;
   Image player;

   // JPanel panel;

   public Layout() {
      // panel = new JPanel();
      // panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //same as the JFrame
      // panel.addKeyListener(new Move(p));
      // panel.setFocusable(true);
      // panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); //background of the maze

      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      addKeyListener(new Move(p));
      setFocusable(true);
      setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      m.generateMaze();
   }

   public void setX(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }

   public int getX() {
      return x;
   }

   public void setY(int y) {
      this.y = y;
   }

   public int getY() {
      return y;
   }

   // public JPanel getPanel() {
   // return panel;
   // }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(p.getPlayerImage(), p.getPlayerX(), p.getPlayerY(), this);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      repaint();
   }
}
```

Another problem is your use of KeyListeners since Key Bindings would be much preferable here, but I'll leave that for your *next* question.

Also, you're adding your JPanel to the JFrame **after** calling `setVisible(true)` on the JPanel -- don't do this. Call `setVisible(true)` only after adding all components.

Comment: I am no longer even getting anything to show up, are you able to show me how I would properly use the JPanel I created in Layout inside of Play (I am having real problems doing this)?

Comment: @user1234: Are you adding the Layout JPanel to your GUI?

Comment: @user1234: ouch. Please don't post code in comments since it loses its formatting making it unreadable. Instead, post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30034015/edit).

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the code to the original JPanel. I want to get this figured out soon so I can start testing and adding more stuff. The new code pertaining to what I am talking about is under the original post; hopefully the problem lies in opne of those two things, otherwise I am completely lost why it is no longer printing even the background.